# how to create an array of elements in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a code like this:

```
Element name = doc.createElement("firstname");
name.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(lastname));
extension.appendChild(name);
```

Now, if I want to make multiple Element names, how do I do then?
I tried to simply make "name" into an array but it didnt work:

```
Element name[] = null;
name[0] = doc.createElement("firstname");
name[0].appendChild(doc.createTextNode(lastname));
extension.appendChild(name[0]);
```

any suggestions?

Comment: That looks a lot like JavaScript. JavaScript is _not_ Java. Java is to JavaScript like Car is to Carpet.

Comment: Intialize `Element name[]`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum It look like perfectly valid Java to me. What makes you think it is JavaScript?

Comment: @Buurman The usage of the DOM API [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) , [`createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode) , [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)

Comment: I do work in JAVA, not JavaScript -_-

Comment: The Java Document class, has the methods `createElement` and `appendChild`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Element name[] = new Element[10]; //or any size
```

name[] is a reference to an object (Element[] is an object as well). If you set the reference to `null` you can't dereference it with `name[0]=`.

Keep in mind that arrays are fixed-size. You might want to look into ArrayList or Vector if you'd like a variable-size datastructure.

Comment: Nice, I get it now :)
Thx for the reply

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Element name[] = new Element[expected_element_number];
name[0] = doc.createElement("firstname");
...
```